# improving skin color detection with histogram evaluation

Tags: image-processing, opencv, histogram, skin

this is my attempt to skin color detection using opencv2 after reading this [cool tutorial](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/back_projection/back_projection.html).

1. take a face with haar
2. use the face ROI histogram 2D (on hue and saturation) to model the skin color, `calcHist`
3. use this model to evaluate a new image with `calcBackProject`
4. apply `dilate`, `erode`, `blur` filters on the result mask.

the better case is this one:
[image]

but there is no background and no lights (only ambiental sun light in the room)

in other cases I obtain really worse result, there are a lot of noise in background, hand fingers are black or noised and so on. and when I'm try to get a 0-1 mask for mask only skin.. the final result is not so good.

maybe I can apply other filters, like threshold, or other technique (some other **clustering** or **filling methods**? I have looked for `floodfill` but I don't have a start point) or **combining more histograms** (rgb histogram for example).. but, how?

all kind of brainstorming are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In this [link](http://www.shervinemami.info/blobs.html) is suggested the use of thresholds in the HSV space. You could create a mask with these thresholds and combine with the back histogram, using a AND operation.

Comment: i know that link. i think it is a really poor approach, it is based on fixed range and could be really conditioned by lights for example